# How to optimize my backup script

Tags: scripts

I'm not vary good at scripting so far :-) but managed to create the individual scripts to backup my Tellico database in each of there individual directories.
Since there are quite a few databases and directories that I want backed up, what I finally did was put all of the individual backup scripts into one single script called Backup-all-Tellico.sh
I was wondering if there was some improvements/suggestions that can be made to make the Backup-all script more efficient and streamlined.

```
#!/bin/bash  
# Modified on 04/13/2020
#Script name Backup-all-Tellico 
#This script is used to run all the backup script in my varous Tellico Database Dirs
#
# ver 1.0
#
#Database/Tellico/Tellico-MyModelLog.tc
#
cd ~/Database/Tellico/My-Models  
   echo   
        DateTimeStamp=$(date '+%d-%m-%y-%H:%M')  
      # FileName=$MyModelLog.tc
    cp MyModelLog.tc ${DateTimeStamp}-MyModelLog.tc
    mv ${DateTimeStamp}-MyModelLog.tc ~/Database/Tellico/My-Models/Backups-Archives
#
#Database/Tellico/Tellico-JeffsSoftware
#
cd ~/Database/Tellico/Tellico-JeffsSoftware/
   echo   
        DateTimeStamp=$(date '+%d-%m-%y-%H:%M')  
       # FileName=$JeffsSoftware-Ver2
    cp JeffsSoftware-Ver2 ${DateTimeStamp}-JeffsSoftware-Ver2
    mv ${DateTimeStamp}-JeffsSoftware-Ver2 ~/Database/Tellico/Tellico-JeffsSoftware/Backups
#
#/Database/Tellico/Tellico-MyBooks/My-Comics
#
cd ~/Database/Tellico/Tellico-MyBooks/My-Comics
   echo   
        DateTimeStamp=$(date '+%d-%m-%y-%H:%M')  
       # FileName=$MyComics-Ver1.0
    cp MyComics-Ver1.0 ${DateTimeStamp}-MyComics-Ver1.0
    mv ${DateTimeStamp}-MyComics-Ver1.0 ~/Database/Tellico/Tellico-MyBooks/My-Comics/Backups
#
#/Database/Tellico/Tellico-MyDVDS
#
cd ~/Database/Tellico/Tellico-MyDVDS
   echo   
        DateTimeStamp=$(date '+%d-%m-%y-%H:%M')  
       # FileName=$MyDVDS.tc
    cp MyDVDS.tc ${DateTimeStamp}-MyDVDS.tc
    mv ${DateTimeStamp}-MyDVDS.tc ~/Database/Tellico/Tellico-MyDVDS/Backups
#
#/Database/Tellico/Tellico-MyHardware
#
cd ~/Database/Tellico/Tellico-MyHardware
   echo   
        DateTimeStamp=$(date '+%d-%m-%y-%H:%M')  
      # FileName=$MyHardware
    cp MyHardware ${DateTimeStamp}-MyHardware
    mv ${DateTimeStamp}-MyHardware ~/Database/Tellico/Tellico-MyHardware/Backups 
#
#/Database/Tellico/Tellico-MyHardware
#
cd ~/Database/Tellico/Tellico-MySubscriptions
   echo   
        DateTimeStamp=$(date '+%d-%m-%y-%H:%M')  
      # FileName=$MySubscriptions
    cp MySubscriptions ${DateTimeStamp}-MySubscriptions
    mv ${DateTimeStamp}-MySubscriptions ~/Database/Tellico/Tellico-MySubscriptions/Backups
#
#/Database/Tellico/Tellico-MySubscriptions
#      
cd ~/Database/Tellico/Tellico-MySubscriptions
   echo   
        DateTimeStamp=$(date '+%d-%m-%y-%H:%M')  
      # FileName=$MySubscriptions
    cp MySubscriptions ${DateTimeStamp}-MySubscriptions
    mv ${DateTimeStamp}-MySubscriptions ~/Database/Tellico/Tellico-MySubscriptions/Backups
#
#/Database/Tellico/Tellico-MyURLS
#
cd ~/Database/Tellico/Tellico-MyURLS      
 echo   
        DateTimeStamp=$(date '+%d-%m-%y-%H:%M')  
      # FileName=$MyInfoUrls-Ver2.0
    cp MyInfoUrls-Ver2.0 ${DateTimeStamp}-MyInfoUrls-Ver2.0
    mv ${DateTimeStamp}-MyInfoUrls-Ver2.0 ~/Database/Tellico/Tellico-MyURLS/Backups   
#  
#/Database/Tellico/Tellico-MyWantList
#    
cd ~/Database/Tellico/Tellico-MyWantList
   echo   
        DateTimeStamp=$(date '+%d-%m-%y-%H:%M')  
       # FileName=$MyWantList.tc
    cp MyWantList.tc ${DateTimeStamp}-MyWantList.tc
    mv ${DateTimeStamp}-MyWantList.tc ~/Database/Tellico/Tellico-MyWantList/Backups
#
```

Answer (score 1):

I think one obvious improvement would be to make a function that backs up each of the dbs/dirs, taking one or more arguments. Let's say there will be difference between dir name and database name, thus using 2 arguments.

Here is a quick example, using yours as a base: (obviously not tested)

```
#!/bin/bash  
# Modified on 04/13/2020
#Script name Backup-all-Tellico 
#This script is used to run all the backup script in my varous Tellico Database Dirs
#
# ver 1.1

# Define function to back up each dir/db
# $1 is dir name, $2 is database name
run_backup() {
   cd ~/Database/Tellico/$1  
   echo   
        DateTimeStamp=$(date '+%d-%m-%y-%H:%M')  
    cp $2 ${DateTimeStamp}-$2
    mv ${DateTimeStamp}-$2 ~/Database/Tellico/$1/Backups
}

# Run backup function for each dir/db

# Database/Tellico/Tellico-MyModelLog.tc
run_backup My-Models MyModelLog.tc

# Database/Tellico/Tellico-JeffsSoftware
run_backup Tellico-JeffsSoftware JeffsSoftware-Ver2

# Database/Tellico/Tellico-MyBooks/My-Comics
run_backup Tellico-MyBooks/My-Comics MyComics-Ver1.0

# Database/Tellico/Tellico-MyDVDS
run_backup Tellico-MyDVDS MyDVDS.tc

etc...
```

I hope I didn't make any errors in the above example.
Besides the obvious benefit of cleaner and shorter code, it also makes it a lot easier to maintain if you want to implement more functionality into the backup function, for instance file checking, handling of error codes etc.